# How do I specify that values in a column must already exist in another table?

Tags: sql, constraints, psql

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    txt character varying(30));

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    t1_id integer,
    t1_txt character varying,
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1(id));
```

For reasons of... um, "optimization", I need t2.t1_txt to exist somewhere in t1, almost as if it were a foreign key, but without a unique constraint. My first question is: what is the best way to do this?

My second question is: with these same tables, what is the best way to force t2.t1_txt to coincide with t1.txt when t2.t1_id = t1.id and how do I get it to cascade updates from t1.txt to t2.t1_txt?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're replicating the value of `txt` between the two tables.  You *can* do that with insert/update triggers, but I would recommend using a *view* instead:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    txt character varying(30));

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    t1_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1(id));

CREATE VIEW t2ANDt1
AS
   SELECT 
     id,
     t1_id,
     t1.txt
   FROM t2
   INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

Comment: That sounds pretty good actually. But for question 1 the idea is a constraint that specifies that t1_txt must exist in t1, without id and t1_id having to coincide. It does sound like a job for triggers... is there any other way?

Comment: Is it possible that I'm misunderstanding the use of foreign keys?

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC I think your requirement sounds strange - _typically_ the foriegn _ID_ is used as the key rather than a non-key _property_. If the _text_ value (which is non-unique in `t1`) needs to exist in t1 then yes I would say handle that with triggers, but ausing `t1_id` would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: So triggers for the first question, and drop column t2.t1_txt and use views instead for question two. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take t1_txt out of table t2

Add t1.id to table t2

Make it a foreign key of t1

Comment: Well, taking t1_txt out of t2 is probably the best thing to do generally speaking, but that's exactly what I don't want in this case. And there is already a foreign key that does that in the example.

Comment: I understand what you saying, but it still does not make sense. Are you saying t2 has one piece of text via t1_ID and another piece of text very confusingly called t1_text which isn't the one t1_id points to? If so, other_t1_id, or perhaps better still a link table would be potential solutions.